# Possible to use 7447 to drive common-cathode 7 segment display?

Tags: integrated-circuit, 7segmentdisplay, ttl

I know that the 74(LS)47 is designed to drive common-anode displays. However, is it possible to make it drive a common-cathode display? What is the simplest (in terms of components) way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. One method would be to use two extra resistors (plus the usual per-segment resistor) and one PNP transistor per output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqy9c2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can buy these three parts integrated into so-called "digital transistors" so it would take only 7 additional parts.

Edit: Re comments by sherrellbc, here is a version for a high-voltage LED digit (something like a 3" digit with multiple LED die per segment) that operates the transistor in the linear region. It provides a constant current of about 15mA for any LED voltage from 0 to more than 10V (it will get warm at 0V).

When it is 'on', the base is at 12V - 2.2V, so the emitter is at about 1.5V below +12 and therefore the collector current will be close to 15mA (since emitter current ~= collector current).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4NFZ3.png)</sup>

Comment: For whatever reason I tend to struggle on the calculations associated with anything other than a basic transistor (without feedback) operated in saturation. So, I can easily see the current through the LED is going to be `(5-Vec-Vd)/R2`, but Vce is a function of the operating point of the transistor. To get the collector current we have to know the base current, which is (sunk into the 7447) `(5 - Veb - Vec)/R3 -> (4.3 - Vec)/R3`. But the fact that `Vec` is a function of the operating point and `R1` is present, I tend to not get these correct.

Comment: If we *know* that the transistor is in saturation then this becomes trivial. But how can we be sure of this?

Comment: @sherrellbc You can assume that the transistor is saturated, so Vec = ~0.1V, and the current is determined mostly by the LED forward voltage drop and the supply voltage- I = (4.9-Vf)/240 ~= 10mA for a 2.4V Vf.

Comment: @sherrellbc We can be sure of this because it's designed so that Ib >> Ic/hfe. In this case, I made Ib = 4.3mA, which is enough for a collector current of 50-100mA (way more than necessary). It would work just as well with a 4.7K resistor.

Comment: So is it that all transistors acting as switching operate in the saturation region? Is the linear region of a transistor used seldom, if at all? I think it's for transistor amplifier circuits, right? Also, I've heard it both ways - does the current through an LED *respond* to the voltage across it (seems logical), or does the voltage drop across the device develop *due to* the current through it?

Comment: I see. That makes a lot of sense and appears to be something that I have forgotten I knew. So, the linear region of operation then would be such that the base current is not sufficiently beyond its maximum point of contribution to an effective increase in Ic. In other words, saturation can be defined as the point at which further increases in Ib do not affect Ic.

Comment: The circuit is designed to be saturated so the transistor saturates. It could be designed to operate in the linear region (as a current source) easily, but I think it's better to use a resistor and let the transistor run cool.

Comment: Pretend I'm really stupid. Could you possibly add a circuit diagram?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, to clarify this once and for all: does the current through an LED respond to the voltage across it (seems logical) making it *voltage controlled*, or does the voltage drop across the device develop due to the current through it making it *current controlled*?

Comment: @sherrellbc If you fix the voltage, the current will go to some value depending on the voltage. If you fix the current, the voltage will go to some value depending on the current. Either way. It so happens that the current increases very quickly with increasing voltage, so it's rare (but not unheard of) to drive LEDs with a constant voltage.

Comment: @felixphew Top diagram should do it for you- just make 7 of them, one for each segment. It might be easier to buy a CA display though, then you only need the 7 240 ohm resistors.

Answer (score 2):

A series of seven [74LS04](https://www.futurlec.com/74LS/74LS04.shtml)s on the output.